Graphics drivers keep crashing when booting up android studio device emulator after I removed wrong drivers
Here is what happend.
I have a surface laptop 4 (AMD-win11) that was running it's custom drivers from microsoft. I use android studio device emulator(virtual device manager) to make android apps. This was working fine. For some reason I thought that installing the graphic drivers from the AMD website would make it better. After I installed the AMD drivers I realized that they weren't the best ones for me as I couldn't adjust brightness with my function keys as I could before.
I attempted to remove the Amddrivers by uninstalling them via several methods device manager, the driver uninstall option from the AMD software and the specific AMD driver remover tool from their website.
After I did that I reinstalled my surface laptop specific drivers and everything seems to work now except android studio emulator throws 4 errors of my graphics driver crashing when I try to start up an emulated device. The device eventually starts up but It freezes frequently and  isn't able to run apps that it could once run properly.
I don't have a system recovery point.  How can I fix this issue without reinstalling windows 11.
the errors
and here is the first part of the "show details" of that error prompt
Operating system: Windows NT
                  10.0.22631 3296
CPU: amd64
     family 23 model 96 stepping 1
     12 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
Crash address: 0x21705a31404
Process uptime: 76 seconds

Thread 113 (crashed)
 0  atio6axx.dll + 0x8b7120


Have you reinstalled the android studio emulator software?

Yes, the problem still persisted even after I made new virtual devices running diffrent versons of android I also updated android studio to the latest version and tried again but the problem still persists

A few hours to make a complete backup of the computer and then refresh Windows 11 may well be the quickest solution :(

If you want to be sure the display drivers have been uninstalled, you can use Display Driver Uninstaller.

Is it possible for the problem to still be there or does a refresh really start you out with a clean slate. Also would I need to redo all the privacy setting and stuff I did to disable telemetry and such again?

I have no experience of refreshing Windows 11. I recently did a "reinstall" of Windows 10 via the "media creation tool" and it retained the settings under "Privacy settings". I guess you might have made more changes which might need to be redone.

Okay, thanks Andrew I'll do a backup/refresh if no one gives me another solution in a couple of days.

Go into Device Manager and delete your AMD graphics device with
its driver.
If this is your only graphics device, you would need to shutdown
Windows with the power button (short press).
After boot, Windows should install back its drivers.
Note that if you have System Restore enabled, you might be able to
rollback Windows to before you installed the AMD drivers.
This could be a much simpler solution.
You might still need to repair or reinstall the android studio
device emulator.
EDIT: The above did not work for the poster, and neither did the
answers from the post
Android Studio, Suddenly got GPU Driver Issue when running emulator.
The poster has then decided to reinstall Windows.

I did this. the problem still occurs even with the basic windows drivers that you get when you remove your AMD ones and reboot the system. I also reinstalled and updated androidstudio and tried different virtual devices with different android versions but the problem persists.

I understand System Restore was disabled? Have you ever installed non-Microsoft graphics drivers? Does the crash also happen with new emulated devices? Does enabling software rendering help?

yes system restore is disabled, yes I did install generic AMD drivers from the AMD website not the surface specific ones and yes It does happen with newly created emulated devices as well.

I meant did you install other AMD drivers before you installed the latest ones that caused the problem. And does enabling software rendering help?

I went from surface specific(1) to AMD generic(2) to windows basic(3) to surface specific(4) drivers

I'm a bit lost with too many drivers, but you could go back to the ones that worked. See also the answers in this post.

That post looks interesting I'll try If that solution works.

It didn't work. I forced it to run with my GPU but it just threw the same error. I'll just make a backup and refresh win11. Anyway, thanks.
